# Как адаптировать шапку для мобильной версии?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, header, адаптивность

Как адаптировать только одно изображение шапки под мобильную версию, чтобы не затрагивать другие картинки на сайте?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media(min-width: 320px) {
  .класс-картинки {
    /* пишешь адаптивность */
  }
}
```

А вообще нужно начинать верстать с мобильной верстки, а уже потом идти на размеры повыше.